# uptime shows no output for non-privileged users

Tags: 12.04, permissions

I have a 12.04LTS system where the uptime command produces no output when run by a normal (that is, not root,) user:

```
bbx@bard:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
bbx@bard:~$ id
uid=1000(bbx) gid=1000(bbx) groups=1000(bbx),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),111(lpadmin),112(sambashare)
bbx@bard:~$ w
 10:42:56 up 21 days, 21:31,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    redacted          10:35    0.00s  0.35s  0.00s w
bbx@bard:~$ uptime
bbx@bard:~$ echo $?
0
```

also...

```
bbx@bard:~$ ls -l /proc/uptime /proc/loadavg
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 21 12:57 /proc/loadavg
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 21 12:57 /proc/uptime
```

And strace output is [available from PasteBin.](http://pastebin.com/sVELNkKb)

Meanwhile, uptime works fine, (output matches the w(1) command,) when invoked by root:

```
root@bard:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@bard:~# uptime
 10:45:49 up 21 days, 21:34,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Could you add the output of `ls -l /proc/uptime /proc/loadavg` to your question? And while you're at it, run `strace uptime > ~/strace-uptime.txt 2>&1`, upload the `~/strace-uptime.txt` file somewhere and link it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the strace provided by you:

```
bbx@bard:~$ more strace-uptime.txt
execve("/home/bbx/bin/uptime", ["uptime"], [/* 15 vars */]) = 0
...
```

Your non-root user `bbx` has a script in `~/bin/uptime` that gets executed. When ran as root, another `uptime` program gets executed. To solve this, check what `/home/bbx/bin/uptime` is doing there and remove it if possible. Otherwise, use the full path (`/usr/bin/uptime`).

Comment: <light bulb> Oh, yes, of course. I forgot that script was in the path for that user. Thanks for looking!